# How can I combine USB-C peripherals into a single cord?

Tags: macbook-pro, usb

I've just acquired my fourth USB-C peripheral. In addition to the charger, that makes five USB-C devices that I want to connect to my Macbook Pro.
Perhaps I want to connect all five at once, but it only has 4 ports or perhaps I just don't want to plug in four cables every time I sit down.
 I've tried searching google and amazon and elsewhere for `/usb(c|-c| c) (hub|splitter)/` and I am only finding solutions for connecting a bunch of older devices to a single USB-C port. Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: Check out this question: http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/2101/is-there-any-usb-c-splitter-in-existence

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: The comment above yours links to a question with a couple of options that have a whopping *two* USB-C ports

Answer (score 2):

You may be searching under the wrong names. I've (personally) not seen any USB-C hubs. Don't know if a "splitter" is even possible. However USB-C is now commonly used as a "dock" connector.

It run at speeds that allow you to connect monitors, video cards and other high bandwidth devices. If you do a Google search for "USB-C dock" you will find a number of devices that have multiple ports on it including (often) multiple USB-C ports.

With a USB-C dock you only need one plug when you connect up at home, everything else is plugged into the dock.

Comment: Can you link to one such product with multiple USB-C ports? I've found dozens to hundreds of "dock" products with just one USB-C port, and not seen a single product with even two such ports.